# Transform pipeline for pug?

Tags: pug

The use case is I have a very simple pug document. I need to create two documents...one that is the original and the other which obfuscates the "private" tags. In order to do that programmatically, I need access to be able to traverse all the tags. Does the pug API provide that functionality?

```
h1 
  private Foobar
p
  Lorem ipsum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tags.pug`

```
-
    let tags = [
        {
            tag: "h1",
            private: true,
            content: "private Foobar"
        },
        {
             tag: "p",
             content: "Lorem ipsum"
        }
    ]
```

In `public.pug`

```
 include tags.pug

 each tag in tags
      if !tag.private
          ...etc
```

In `private.pug`

```
 include tags.pug

 each tag in tags
      ...etc
```

Comment: i like this approach... is it possible for a PUG file to read a command line argument? (That way you don't need an extra PUG file.)

Comment: @UAvalos not that I know of but you could do that with Node JS

Comment: @UAvalos format it like I did with a hypen, line break, and indent

Comment: You can totally read command line args!  `const args = process.args`

Comment: I really like this approach... It forces you to do a clean separation of data/display. The doc would go into a JSON, the PUG would read/transform the JSON, then output an HTML! Thanks for the tip